# Why are capital letters missing in title of reference (using plos2009.bst)?

Tags: bibtex, capitalization

I'm using the [plos2009.bst](http://www.plosone.org/static/plos2009.bst) file to generate my references. However, there seems to be a bug in the .bst File since the formatation of the references is not correct. E.g. there are no capital letters in the title of the cited paper.

plos2009.bst generates:

> Kortner TM, Gu J, Krogdahl A, Bakke AM (2012) Transcriptional regulation of cholesterol and bile acid metabolism after dietary soyabean meal treatment in atlantic salmon (salmo salar l.). BJN : 1–12.

but it should look like:

> Kortner TM, Gu J, Krogdahl A, Bakke AM (2012) Transcriptional regulation of cholesterol and bile acid metabolism after dietary soyabean meal treatment in **Atlantic** salmon (**Salmo salar L.**). BJN : 1–12.

Comment: You will need to fix your `.bib` file. Bibtex is not clever enough to identify proper nouns!, so you need to protect relevant words with braces: `title = {Transcriptional regulation of cholesterol and acid metabolism after dietary soyabean meal treatment in {Atlantic} salmon ({Salmo} salar {L.})}`

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: Thanks, using {} works. However, I'm actually not that keen to go through all my citations and fix that (I have one huge .bib file). So I'm wondering if there is a simple fix to the .bst file. For example I do not encounter that problem when using the BMCgenomics.bst file...